# Avro compatibility when only documentation of some of the field changes

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I have been using avro as the data format for offline processing over kafka in my application. I have a use case where the producer uses a schema which is almost same as what is used by consumer except that producer has some changes in the documentation of some fields. Would the consumer be able to consume such events without erroring out? I'm debugging an issue where numerous events are missing in the data pipeline and trying to figure out the root cause. I noticed this difference and want to understand if at all this causes an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably test to confirm, but documentation should not impact schema resolution as the schema should get normalized to the "canonical form":
https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#Parsing+Canonical+Form+for+Schemas

Comment: Yes I tested this out and found that doc change does not really affect. Thanks!